# Is it OK to place AdMob banner under bottom app navigation buttons in full screen on Android?

Tags: android, mobile, admob, banner-ads

I want to display the AdMob bottom banner as close to the screen's bottom as possible. My app is displayed in full screen mode, so the bottom app navigation buttons are not visible by default.
However, if I place a banner in the bottom, there is, in my opinion, possibility of accidentally clicking the banner. It happens when you swipe from bottom to top to show bottom app navigation buttons. Additionally, when the bottom banner is shown for a few seconds, it is for sure not recommended because of mistake ["Ads adjacent to interactive elements" in Discouraged banner implementations](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6275345?hl=en#zippy=%2Cclick-to-view-an-example).
Also, I've seen some popular games which do it with AdMob Banners in full screen, so it feels like if they are not banned, then it is OK.

Is it OK to place AdMob bottom banner under bottom app navigation buttons in full screen?

The screenshots which show this situation
Before swipe:
[image: AdMob banner before swipe]

After swipe:
[image: AdMob banner after swipe]

Answer (score 2):

No don't do that. It will diminish your users experience. Masan has also given a good explanation on why not to use it

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**

Long answer: **Not recommended**

If your app has a little amount of downloads, accidental clicks can be critical and get your account suspended.

If your app has a big amount of downloads, **you may or may not be able to get away with it.**

Try experimenting with [native ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/native/start).

Comment: Regarding a little or a big amount of downloads, is it based on your own experience or another's experience? Also, I don't think that my case is a viable for native ads. Can they be shown under the bottom app navigation buttons instead of banner?

Comment: @CyxouD It's based on my own experience. Ad serving was limited for a month and a half.